# Generic Vs Dependency injection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, dependency-injection

Is there any difference between Generic Classes and Dependency injection ? <strike>Are they not ways to implement Inversion of Control</strike>

Is generic class not a way to implement Dependency Injection with added benefits of compile time safety ?

For Example, if I have a node class, then I can define as following

```
class Node<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
  ..
  ..
}

class Node
{
   ISomeInterface obj
   public Node(ISomeInterface inject)
   {
       obj = inject;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
With New

```
class Node<T> where T : ISomeInterface, new()
{
  ISomeInterface obj
  public Node()
  {
     obj = new T();
  }
}
```

**Update 3**
@akim : I have made the example that you asked for using Generics
Repository using Generics

```
Interface IRepository 
{   
      public DataTable GetAll();
}

public class ProductRep : IRepository
{ 
       public DataTable GetAll()
       {
            //implementation
       }
}

public class MockProductRep : IRepository
{ 
       public DataTable GetAll()
       {
            //mock implementation
       }
}

public class Product<T> where T : IRepository, new()
{
    IRepository repository = null
     public Product()
     {
       repository = new T();
     }
    public List<Product> GetProduct()
    {
      DataTable prodlst =  repository.GetAll();
      //convert to List of products now
    }
}


//so while using the Product class, client would Supply ProductRep class and in NUnit you //would supply MockProductRep class

Product<ProductRep> obj = new ProductRep<ProductRep>();
List<Product> lst = obj.GetProduct();

//in NUnit
Product<MockProductRep> obj = new ProductRep<MockProductRep>();
List<Product> lst = obj.GetProduct();
```

Comment: If you down vote, then please consider adding comments on why you down voted.

Comment: Did somebody convince you that "generics approach" is a bad practice? I'm not convinced by answers in the topic, because the benefits of IoC over "generics approach" is connected only with late binding. But the most of apps don't need this feature. So, what is your opinion now, Anand?

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.  Generic types allow you to define functionality that can be applied to a wide range of other types.  However when you instantiate a generic class, the compiler makes a reference to the actual types that were passed as generic parameters.  So the declaration is static and cannot change after compilation.  For example, I can write code that instantiates your Node class:

```
Node<SomeImplementation> node1 = new Node<SomeImplementation>();
Node<SomeOtherImplementation> node2 = new Node<SomeOtherImplementation>();
```

I am reusing your Node class in different scenarios, but once I have compiled my assembly, I cannot change the generic type of my variables (node1 and node2).

Dependency Injection (and IoC containers), on the other hand, allow you to change the functionality of your app at **runtime**.  You can use Dependency Injection to swap out one implementation of `ISomeInterface` with a totally different implementation at runtime. For example, in your second node class, I can use an IoC container to create the Node class... something like:

```
Node n = Container.Create<Node>();
```

The IoC container then figures out how to instantiate the Node class based on some configuration.  It determines that the constructor needs an implementation of `ISomeInterface`, and it knows how to build an implementation at **runtime**.  I can change my configuration for the IoC container and execute the same assembly/code and a different implementation of `ISomeInterface` will be created and passed to the constructor of Node.

This is useful in unit tests, because you can mock out certain parts of your application so that one specific class can be tested.  For example, you may want to test some business logic that usually accesses a database.  In your unit test, you can mock your data access logic and inject new functionality that returns 'static' data that is needed to test each particular business case.  This breaks your tests dependency on the database and allows for more accurate/maintainable testing.

**Edit**

With regards to your update, the parameter-less constructor restriction may not always be desired.  You may have a class (written by you or a third party) that requires parameters.  Requiring a class to implement a parameter-less constructor may effect the integrity of the application.  The idea behind the DI pattern is that your Node class doesn't need to know how the class was actually created.

Suppose you had many layers of classes/dependencies.  With generic types, it might look like this:

```
class MyClass<T>
    where T : IUtilityClass
{
    ...
}

class UtilityClass<T> : IUtilityClass
    where T : IAnotherUtilityClass
{
    ...
}

class AnotherUtilityClass : IAnotherUtilityClass
{
    ...
}
```

In this case, MyClass uses UtilityClass, and UtilityClass depends on AnotherUtilityClass.  So when you declare `MyClass`, you must know every dependency down the line... not just the dependencies of `MyClass`, but also the dependencies of `UtilityClass`.  This declaration looks something like this:

```
MyClass<UtilityClass<AnotherUtilityClass>> myTestClass =
    new MyClass<UtilityClass<AnotherUtilityClass>>();
```

This would get cumbersome as you add more and more dependencies.  With DI, your caller doesn't need to know about any of the nested dependencies because the IoC container automatically figures them out.  You just do something like this:

```
MyClass myTestClass = Container.Create<MyClass>();
```

There's no need to know anything about the details of MyClass or it's utility classes.

There are usually other benefits to IoC containers as well, for example many of them provide forms of Aspect Oriented Programming.  They also allow you to specify the lifetime of an object, so an object could be a singleton (only one instance will be created, and the same instance will be returned to all callers).

Comment: Though the declaration is static but at the client's end. This is what I suppose Dependecy Injection does. The Node class would not know about which object it would get. So the control for the behaviour is with the client.

Comment: Correct... generic types offer some of the same benefits, but they are not quite as flexible/dynamic as dependency injection.

Comment: I think I phrased my question incorrectly.
Can you add some benefits of implementing DI with Constructor injection vs Generic method implementation ?

Comment: See my updated 2. Now with the help of Generics, I have given constraints. SO any implementation of Type T, not matching these criteria would even be caught at compile type which I think is huge advantage

Comment: With your example, the Generics is definitely looking ugly

Comment: Yeah, that's not the type of code I want to maintain :).  I don't think generics were designed for that type of nesting.  They are awesome on the small scale, but I think DI is targeting a different need.  With DI, you don't lose all compile time checks either.  You still define the interfaces that your classes depend on, it's just the creation of the objects that can cause runtime exceptions if your configuration settings are wrong.  Then again, there are tools that automatically create dependency mappings to help with that, too.

Answer (score 3):

**Generics** introduce the concept of type parameters, which make it possible *to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types* until the class or method is declared and instantiated by code [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). And generics with all their restrictions and check are *applied during compile time* using *static analysis*.

In other hand, **Dependency injection** is a software design pattern that allows a choice of component to be made *at run-time rather than compile time* [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  And object coupling is bound at run time by an assembler object and is typically *not known at compile time using static analysis* [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

**Answer on your question**: one applied at compile time using static analysis, another applied at run time using XML or in-code configuration (it should be also valid for compile). Using  **Dependency injection** decision about binding will be postponed until more information or configuration will be available from the context. So generics and dependency injection are different, and used for different purpose.

Sample #3 answer

Let's move one step further and provide `Repository<Entity>` to `Controller` and think about it usage. How are you going to implement controler's constructor:

```
public ControlFreakController<Repository<Entity>>()
{
    this.repository = new Repository<Entity>(); // here is a logical problem
}
```

or

```
public ControllerWithInjection(IRepository repository)
{
   this.repository = repository;
}
```

And how will you cover `ControlFreakController` with tests, if it depends on `Repository<Entity>` (literally hardcoded)? What if `Repository<Entity>` has no default constructor, and has its own dependencies and life time (for example, there should be one and only one repository rep HTTP request)? What if next day it will be required to audit work with `Repository<Entity>`?

Comment: Dear Akim. Thanks for your reply. But I am not interested in MSDN and WIKI. I want your original thoughts on the problem.

Comment: That's a valid point about Static Type and Run time binding but DI(implementation Technique of IoC) is all about giving control to the client for the any behaviour, which could be done with generics also.

Comment: Dear Anand, I have updated answer, but advice you to take a look at already mentioned resources. Belive that you could find much more difference between generics and dependency injection. For example, DI could build different application based upon configuration, or could decorate dependency using Dynamic Proxy at runtime and completely change behaviour of coupled object. Thus you'll find by yourself that they are on different levels of abstraction, and question about comparison between them will provides you much more interesting cases how to use both of them.

Comment: _is all about giving control to the client for the any behaviour, which could be done with generics_ — imagine how will how give control to client over type of database configuration using XML from `web.config` at application start, and in same time apply fake database during unit-testing. And you'll start applied _constructor injection_ in terms of _dependency injection_, but not _generics_.

Comment: If I understand your query correctly, then you want to implement a repository pattern. So that your actual code gets an instance of database where as your NUnits gets fake objects. COrrect ?

Comment: Yes, `Repository` could be an example. DI is all about _composition_, _life-time_ and -_interception_ at run-time, i.e. late binding. It is hard to achive same abilities with generics, because they designed to extend behaviour during compile time. So they are different, but nevertheless it is possible to bind generics using DI. And DI fluent interfaces use generics at code level.

Comment: Update 3 is fine. Let's move one step further and provide `Repository<Entity>` to `Controller` and think about it usage. How are you going to implement controler's constructor: `public ControlFreakController<Repository<Entity>>(){ this.repository = new Repository<Entity>(); }` or `public ControllerWithInjection(IRepository repository){ this.repository = repository; }`. And how will you test `ControlFreakController` if it depends on `Repository<Entity>`? What is `Repository<Entity>` has no default constructor, and has its own dependencies?

Comment: Hi Could you please write your code in your response. Its pretty difficult to read and understand from here. Also in the generic example please use IRepository and IEntity. I know what you are pointing at but just want to be super clear

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean your generic class to look like this:

```
class Node<T> where T : ISomeInterface {
    T obj;

    public Node(T inject) {
        obj = inject;
    }
}
```

..in which case, you're just opening up a generic type for dependency injection (with a restraint). You haven't discovered a different "method" of dependency injection - it is still dependency injection.

This wouldn't be very useful in a "real-world" scenario. You've made assumptions on how the type parameter would be used purely based on injecting it and restraining it. Also, you'll only ever be able to inject 1 single type of object into this, which is a very bad assumption.

After your update using new(), you've got even more issues. Your injected type must allow parameterless construction. That limits you even further.

Comment: Had to edit my post, I thought there was a new() restraint.. whoops.

Comment: I did not get your "Also, you'll only ever be able to inject 1 single type of object into this" point

Comment: How ? Constructor are not the only way to inject dependency. DI is even implemented by using Property Injection. In that case also, you have parameterless constructor

Comment: The new() restraint means that whatever you're injecting must supply a public parameterless constructor. What if the type you're injecting also requires injection?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14606/discussion-between-simon-whitehead-and-anand)

Comment: With DI, I am only concerned about the Type that I would be working. Now the type that has to be inject would be with the client(The behaviour is controlled by client and hence Inversion of Control, it is called). The client injecting that Type will have responsibility  to create a parameter less constructor, in addition with the parameterized constructor for its own injection.

Comment: I am very sorry. I can not connect to this chat(access blocked in office) :((

Comment: Could you come on any IM ? I was just loving this discussion. :)

Comment: "What if the type you're injecting also requires injection?" - Upon delving on this point, I think you are correct. The things would get more complex in this scenario with Generics